# advanced javascript script xpages

Tags: xpages

after buying mastering xpages , XPages Portable Command Guide and xpages extension library . i am confused from where to start i took a look in those ebook and i downloaded their applications from official website but i am confused from where to start . 
i start developping some masks , views and xpages .
my problem is how to relate those masks together ?
example :
i have mask1 with 5 fields , which field1 is related with field1.1 from mask2 . how can i relate them together and how to make them in the same view ????

Comment: Sorry, I have to ask this: Do you know the difference between a document based database and a relational db?

Comment: yes all applications i have developped before was with relational database and that was easy to design with uml but it is the first time that i develop with NoSql database like notes documents . 
i know that lotus domino is a document based database but i am new here and i am trying to find a lead and learn . 
may i change my idea about relating my masks ?

Comment: Hmm... The problem is that your question is not specific enough for a platform like stackoverflow.com. But you can find a lot of usefull informations here: http://www-10.lotus.com/ldd/ddwiki.nsf/xpDocViewer.xsp?lookupName=Domino+Designer+Tutorial#action=openDocument&content=catcontent&ct=prodDoc

Comment: thanks i will take all the tutorial availble on the net and may be i can understand domino and mastering it .

Comment: The correct order for those books is Mastering XPages, then XPages Extension Library (in the introduction we say we expect you've read Mastering XPages). XPages Portable Command Guide stands outside those, designed specifically as a reference book of properties for tuning XPages applications and the XSP client-side object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Matux use [my cheatsheet](http://www.wissel.net/blog/d6plinks/learning-xpages) as starter. It provides lots of links to tutorials and information. Then let go of relational/uml thinking. In an RDBMS you need master/detail tables that in Notes you can store in a single document (depending on the task at hand). The biggest learning step are the multi-value fields, so watch out for them. Security is sweet with declarative read and read/write access per document, but needs careful planning to get performance right.